# Как программно заполнить поля логин и пароль и нажать на кнопку вход?

Tags: javascript

На странице имеется поле ввода input "логин", "пароль" и кнопка входа.
Поля ввода "пароль" и кнопка вход - заранее деактивированы, они активируются только если сначало ввести логин, потом пароль и после можно будет нажать на кнопку вход.

Когда я пытаюсь программно заполнить поля, типа `document.getElementById('id_username').value='myLogin';`, поле логин заполняется значением "myLogin", но поле пароль не активируется, его состояние по прежнему "disabled", а если я мышкой кликаю по текст боксу пароль активируется... А почему программно не получается активировать поля непонятно...
Как программно заполнить эти поля и кликать по кнопке?

Comment: событие скорее всего стоит `onclick`, нужно изменить на `onchange`. пожалуйста приведите по больше кода

Comment: Добавил скриншот,. Мне скорее всего нужно установить фокус, подскажите пожалуйста как установить фокус?

Comment: ты можешь просто атрибут disabled убрать

Comment: на вопросе стоит метка javascript, а на скриншоте вы прикрепили html код. прикрепите часть html и javascript кода. Только не в формате скриншота

Comment: @Grundy - а как убрать атрибут disabled?

Comment: например воспользовавшись методом [`.removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

Comment: или `document.getElementById('id_password').disabled = false;`

Comment: @Grundy - Это сработало! Спасибо большое!

Comment: @gfd2 - Это сработало! Спасибо большое!